# Slow DB Migration in Entity Framework code first migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-migrations

Using the standard way to upgrade my db takes 7 seconds which is way too slow as my database has 3 tables with 5 fields each and practically no data.

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
//Update database to latest migration
migrator.Update();
```

Using Entity Framework 6.0.

This code runs everytime I start my app and it's killing my performance. Why is so slow? Anyway to speed it up?

Here's my app.config:

```
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
<remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<entityFramework>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
</providers>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: Same here, any way you solved this? Waiting for 10-30 seconds for 3 tables is.... hardly efficient.

Comment: Same here! Would love a solution or an explanation

Comment: Same here... anyone found solution for it?